# width to height formula for hexagon

Tags: geometry

Is there a formula to calculate the height (*a*) of a regular hexagon when you know it's width (*b*)?

[image]

Is it possible to adapt this formula to a sum like :

```
b = a + a*x
```

Comment: The half-height $a/2$ and the half-width $b/2$ are the altitude and base of an equilateral triangle.  The ratio between these is $b/a=2/\sqrt{3}$.  So $b=2a/\sqrt{3}=a+a\cdot(2\sqrt{3}-3)/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a line from the centre to the upper left vertex. You now have a right angled triangle and some trigonometry will soon allow you to relate $a$ to $b$.

Comment: More so trigonometry, as you know the angles in a regular hexagon.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia article on hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon) states that a height-to-width ratio of a regular hexagon is 1:1.1547005.

So although trigonometry can do this, you can also use:

> a = b * 0.8660254

Comment: how is it calculated that number?

Comment: @nkint In the parameters section of the Wikipedia page, it notes that `d = sqrt(3) / 2 * D`.  In this context `d` is the value called `a` in the OP's post, and `D` is the value called `b`.  If you evaluate sqrt(3) / 2 it comes out to 0.8660254